# Several Azure AD. New-MsolServicePrincipal : Access Denied

Tags: azure, sharepoint-2013, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, accesscontrolservice

I want to set my Azure Active Directory as an identity provider for SharePoint 2013 Foundation. I activated Azure trial from account that is a part of another infrastructure (my company's infrastructure). So what i have now:

- Azure VM with SharePoint 2013 Foundation installed. Created by me for testing purposes
- Azure Active Directory that is a part of my company's infrastructure. I don't have any permissions even to view it. But I see it since my company uses it
- Azure Active Directory with me as Global Admin (my-ad-name). Created by me for testing purposes
- Access Control Services. Created by me for testing purposes

So following the article [Using Microsoft Azure Active Directory for SharePoint 2013 authentication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn635311.aspx) i get error

```
PS C:\Users\tu1> New-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalNames @("https://my-ad-name.accesscontrol.windo
ws.net/") -DisplayName "Test ACS Namespace" -Addresses $replyUrl
The following symmetric key was created as one was not supplied m2XQJAeUKEQztjn/sEDJwy8TbG8jPxpw6cemkm8Fnkw=
New-MsolServicePrincipal : Access Denied. You do not have permissions to call this cmdlet.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalNames @("https://my-ad-name.accesscon ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [New-MsolServicePrincipal], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.AccessDeniedException,Microsoft.Online.Admini
   stration.Automation.NewServicePrincipal
```

May that be because of the Azure AD that I don't have rights on? Are there ways to connect Access Control Service only with the AD i need?

Comment: Which Azure AD directory did you try to run this cmdlet in? (Note that the directory you're running in will be defined by the username you use to sign in.)

Comment: I didn't specifiy one explicitly. Can I do that? What I did is ran `connect-msolservice` and entered my credentials

Comment: Did you use your credentials from your company's infrastructure? Or credentials for a user in your new directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you connect to Azure AD PowerShell using `Connect-MsolService`, the username you use to sign in will define which directory you are working in. External users (users originally from one directory present in a second directory) cannot be used.

Say, for instance, you have user `bob@contoso.com`, in a directory which we'll identify by the verified domain name `contoso.com`. If `bob@contoso.com` uses the Azure portal to create a new directory (identified here by it's initial domain name `fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com`), the first user (and admin) will be an *external user* `bob@contoso.com`.

In order to connect to Azure AD PowerShell in the context of `fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com`, a *new* "native" user needs to be created in that directory. So, for instance, if `admin@fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com` is created as an admin in `fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com`, that new user account would be able to sign in to Azure AD PowerShell and create a new service principal.

Note: You can always confirm which directory you're working in by using `Get-MsolCompanyInformation`.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. Following your comment I just created global admin in my Azure AD and got it rolling.